# a javascript button that takes x and goes to the a+x+b link

Tags: javascript, button

i want a javascript  form that takes text and make it x , and goes to the new link by a button .
href="aaa"+x+"bbb"

i tried on Html and i cant do that !

```
enter code here

<form action="/my/link/location" method="get"   >
<input type="text" name="url" >
<input type="submit" value="Go" name="Submit" id="frm1_submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: You do realize your question is about JavaScript and you tagged it Java right?

Comment: No problem, but you may want to read the [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onSubmit="submitForm()" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" name="Submit" id="frm1_submit" /> 
</form>
<script>
  function submitForm() {
    window.location = 'aaa'+document.getElementById('url').value+'bbb';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "go to the link"? now when you click on the button, it redirects you to the address "aaa"+what's in the input+"bbb". Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: tanx man . as u know ,i changed aaa and bbb  . when i insert "https://www.google.com/" in the text box , the result in my browser's address bar is "file:///C:/Users/Milad/Desktop/nnnnn.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&Submit=Go " . as u see A and B arent in the address and noting changed. i want it to act like a internet link  .  Help please .

Comment: In that case, change the line with window.location like this: `window.location = 'https://www.google.com'+document.getElementById('url').value+'whatever';`

Comment: and add `return false;` on another line after the one with window.location

Comment: the result is just like the last comment of mine . i dont want to add google .  i want  this :: 
window.location = 'http://begaz.ir/manager/check/mnm.php?url='+document.getElementById('url').value+'&cat=2&sub=121&model=1166';
__but the result is ::
file:///C:/Users/Milad/Desktop/nnnnn.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.takhtegaz.com%2Fautos%2Fpeugeot%2Fpeugeou-persia%2Fpersia-lx%2Fpjw-prs-lx-1394-253035.html%3Frequest%3Dlnp_browse_category&Submit=Go
as u see , there is just middle link in new link . __
and there is address of file in the begining and "&Submit=Go" at the end . please help . tanx

Comment: try to give `return false;` also here: `onSubmit="submitForm(); return false;"`